# Constructing an object which changes its state each time it is accessed and behaves like a variable

Tags: python, properties

I want to construct an object with a special behaviour and I'm pretty sure it can be done with python (with generator, or some kind of tricky class definition).

I basically want an object–let's call it– `colourgun`, which returns a colour from a list of predefined colours, each time I access it. So it should behave like a simple variable, but change it's behaviour each time it is accessed.

You can see a somewhat similar concept in the following example:

```
class CounterList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(CounterList, self).__init__(*args)
        self.counter = 0
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        self.counter += 1
        return super(CounterList, self).__getitem__(index)
```

An instance of `CounterList` increases the `counter` each time the list is accessed, since `__getitem__` is called.

My `colourgun` should be able to detect when it's "used" and behave something like this:

```
>>> gun = Colourgun() # or a function, a generator, whatever...
>>> print gun
'predefined_colour1'
>>> print gun
'predefined_colour2'
>>> print gun
'predefined_colour3'
>>> print gun # no more colours left: reloading and maybe warn the user
[WARNING] automatically reloading the gun
'predefined_colour1'
>>> gun.load(['colour1', 'colour2', 'colour3']) # some way to load it with colours
>>> print gun
'colour1'
>>> print gun
'colour2'
>>> gun.reload() # manually reloading
>>> print gun
'colour1'
```

The point is, I don't want to explicitly call the method for "shooting a colour" each time i access the variable. I guess this is a sign that the variable should indeed be a function or a generator (which can at least freeze its state).

I experimented a bit and this is one attempt to get closer to the idea, but it does not work, since I'm binding the return value of Shoot() and not the function itself to the variable `gun`:

```
class ColourGun(object) :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.colours = ['predefined_colour1', 'predefined_colour2', 'predefined_colour3']
        self.counter = 0
    def Shoot(self) :
        c = self.colours[self.counter]
        self.counter += 1
        return c

gun = ColorGun().Shoot()

print gun
print gun
print gun
```

Which of course prints out `predefined_colour1` three times…

So there is surely a concept based on generators or a composition of classes and generators or something, which can do it in a pythonic way. (or maybe a design pattern?)

P.S.: Let me know if you have an idea for a better title and feel free to add more tags…

**UPDATE**

So doing it with properties (as wim suggested):

```
class ColorGun(object) :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.colours = ['predefined_colour1', 'predefined_colour2', 'predefined_colour3']
        self.counter = 0
    @property
    def Shoot(self) :
        if self.counter >= len(self.colours) :
            self.counter = 0
            print "automatically reloading"
        c = self.colours[self.counter]
        self.counter += 1
        return c

gun = ColorGun()

print gun.Shoot
print gun.Shoot
print gun.Shoot
print gun.Shoot
```

Which gives the output:

```
predefined_colour1
predefined_colour2
predefined_colour3
automatically reloading
predefined_colour1
```

Implementing a `reload` method is no problem, but can I somehow get rid of that `.`, so I can call it like `gun` instead of `gun.Shoot`? ;-)

Comment: You want to look at properties.

Comment: Ah OK thanks, I think I got the idea…

Comment: How do you get rid of that `.`? `gun = ColorGun().Shoot`.

Comment: See the accepted answer: you use the fact, that `__str__` is called, whenever the variable is requested as a string. So you modify `__str__` to return its property `colour` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this...?

```
import itertools as it

class ColourGun(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._colourgen = it.cycle(['predefined_colour1', 'predefined_colour2', 'predefined_colour3'])

    def load(self, colours):
        self._colourgen = it.cycle(colours)

    @property
    def colour(self):
        return next(self._colourgen)

    def __str__(self):
      return self.colour

gun = ColourGun()
print gun
print gun
print gun
gun.load(['potato', 'spam', 'eggs'])
print gun
print gun
```

Comment: nice. don't mean to hijack the thread, but can you give examples when this kind of technique is useful? I understand property and ``__str__`. Not sure if this is answerable. Thanks

Comment: @CppLearner I'm using this when I generate a bunch of plots and want to use my own colour spectrum. Now I can use `gun` or whatever name it has as a variable which changes the colour each time, so multiple lines in a single plot are printed with different colours.

Comment: Properties are useful where you need something fancy to have on attribute getting, setting or deleting.  A common usage example would be restricting an attribute so that it can only be set to a controlled group of inputs.

Comment: This will only work when you call `str` on the object though... such as when printing. Not for the general case of access.

Comment: No you're mistaken, it will cycle any time colour is accessed.

Comment: Sure, of course. Whenever you do `gun.colour`. But not `new_colour = gun`

Answer (score 2):

Since your `being used` means `print gun`, let's just customize the `__str__` method.

```
class ColorGun:

    def __init__(self):
        self.colors = ['red', 'pink']
        self.i = 0

    def __str__(self):
        if not self.colors:
            return

        if self.i >= len(self.colors):
            print '[WARNING] automatically reloading the gun.'
            self.reload()

        c = self.colors[self.i]
        self.i += 1

        return c

    def reload(self, colors=None):
        if colors:
            self.colors = colors
        self.i = 0

gun = ColorGun()
print gun
print gun
print gun
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to customize `__str__` function to achieve that purpose. Here a simple example.

This example shows Items of `mylist` (you can have a generator instead) and when it got exhausted, it prints a default value.

```
class Gun():
    mylist=[1,2,3]
    index=-1
    default='Default'
    def __str__(self):
        try:
            self.index+=1
            return str(self.mylist[self.index])
        except IndexError:
            return self.default


>>> gun=Gun()
>>> print gun
1
>>> print gun
2
>>> print gun
3
>>> print gun
Default
>>>
```